# How do I create dynamic friendly urls for a query string?

Tags: .htaccess

So currently I have URLs that looks like this:

```
http://localhost/?v=register
http://localhost/?v=profile&u=thatgerhard
```

I want the above to look like this:

```
http://localhost/register/ (without trailing /)
http://localhost/profile/thatgerhard/ (without trailing /)
```

I spent a ton of time trying to get this to work even though it seems like it should be a simple fix.

This is what I have atm:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^((.)*)$ /?v=$1&p=$
```

I would ideally like this to be dynamic so that if you do ?v=foo it will automatically do /foo/ without adding "foo" to the htaccess file.

Any help or direction will be greatly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`RewriteCond` Directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) and **RewriteCond backreferences**. The `%1` backreference matches the query string parameter `v`, the `%2` backreference matches the query string parameter `u`. The `RewriteRule` redirects the request permanently and discard the query string entirely.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^v=([^&]*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /%1/? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^v=([^&]*)&u=([^&]*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /%1/%2/? [R=301,L]
```